# Can not set focus on a table row

Tags: javascript, interop, blazor

I am trying to set a focus on a table row at component initialization and i get a null when using `interop`

```
<table  class='table'>
     <thead>
         <tr>value</tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody>          
        @foreach (var elem in this.data) {
           <tr id="@elem.toString()"><td>@elem</td></tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>


@functions()
{
     protected int []data=new int[]{1,2,3,34};
     protected override async Task OnInitAsync() {
                if (data.Length > 0) {
                    var elementName= data.First().ToString();
                    await JSRuntime.Current.InvokeAsync<string>("methods.focus", elementName);;
                }
            }

}
```

**Interop**

```
window.methods={
    focus: function (elementName) { //i get the right id 
            var element = document.getElementById(elementName);//returns null
            element.focus();
        }
}
```

**P.S** I get the right `elementName` in the `focus` method when debugging in the browser but `document.getElementById`returns a null element.Do i need to first get the table element and then search the row in it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set the focus on a td or tr elements. However, you can place an input element within the td element and then set the focus.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I would also add that you should use an ElementRef vs. ID. ElementRef is the "blazor way" of doing this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-components/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0#capture-references-to-components

Answer (score 0):

To become a `<TR>` element focusable, it should to have `tabindex` attribute. [Quoting docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex):

> The tabindex global attribute allows developers to make HTML elements focusable, allow or prevent them from being sequentially focusable (usually with the Tab key, hence the name) and determine their relative ordering for sequential focus navigation.

For your code:

```html
<tr id="@elem.toString()" tabindex="2"><td>@elem</td></tr>
```

Here is an example of a focusable `<hr>` (with js instead of Blazor. Be free to test with Blazor as your own)

```js
const id1= document.getElementById("id3");
id1.focus();
```

```html
<table  class='table'>
     <thead>
         <tr>value</tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody>                  
           <tr id="id1" tabindex="2"><td>My element 1</td></tr>
           <tr id="id2" tabindex="2"><td>My element 2</td></tr>
           <tr id="id3" tabindex="2"><td>My element 3</td></tr>
           <tr id="id4" tabindex="2"><td>My element 4</td></tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```